# Civimail Reports Errors

Tags: civimail, reports

I recently updated CiviCRM and am now having errors with the CiviMail reports. My setup uses:

**CiviCRM 5.32.2**

**Drupal    7.77**

**PHP 7.4**

Below is the step-by-step description of what happens.

1. Click on **Mailings** in CiviCRM
2. Select **Scheduled and Sent Mailings**
3. Click on any completed mailing **Report**
4. Click on any of the **report items** having more than 50 results--"successful deliveries" or "unique opens," etc.
   When I do this, I get the list of contacts and 3 errors are logged in the Drupal logs. They are:

_********ERROR 1********

> Location: http://mysite.org/civicrm/report/instance/33?mailing_id_value=390&
> qfKey=54cfb81fd804cbcd6b07435da277f9354ce7ca54fd178e9_4603&force=1&crmPID=3&
> snippet=json
>
> Referrer: http://mysite.org/civicrm/report/instance/33?reset=1&mailing_id_value=390
>
> Message: Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in HTML_QuickForm->addElement()
> (line 648 of
> /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm.php).

_********ERROR 2********

> Location: http://mysite.org/civicrm/report/instance/33?mailing_id_value=390&
> qfKey=54cfb81fd804cbcd6b07435da277f9354ce7ca54fd178e9_4603&force=1&crmPID=3&
> snippet=json
>
> Referrer: http://mysite.org/civicrm/report/instance/33?reset=1&mailing_id_value=390
>
> Message:  Warning: array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array,
> null given in HTML_QuickForm->addElement() (line 648 of
> /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm.php).

_********ERROR 3********

> Location: http://mysite.org/civicrm/report/instance/33?mailing_id_value=390&
> qfKey=54cfb81fd804cbcd6b07435da277f9354ce7ca54fd178e9_4603&force=1&crmPID=3&
> snippet=json
>
> referrer: http://mysite.org/civicrm/report/instance/33?reset=1&mailing_id_value=390
>
> Message: Notice: Undefined index: class in HTML_QuickForm->addElement() (line 649 of
> /home/mysite/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm.php).

5. Next, click the up arrow on the upper right of the list for going to the next page of contacts. Once again the same 3 errors above are added to the Drupal Log.

[image: screen shot of Drupal error log after step 4]

6. The page loads with the following form and SQL query (see image) and the up-arrow is gone from the paging. One time, the top toolbar drop-downs also stopped working.
   [image: screen shot of page that loads after the first page.]

My question is: Why is this quickform displaying when you go to page 2 or any page past the first one? Insights, please?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on the latest dev version. Perhaps it is already fixed?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. **CiviCRM 5.32.2** **Wordpress 5.6** **PHP 7.2** Seems to be a problem introduced just recently as I didn't notice it a couple of patches ago. Was made aware of it by the mail_report cronjob running on the server. Got an email saying PHP Warning: array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm.php on line 648 ...and then some HTML, JS and a bit of PHP, probably from the mailing template the message is referring to.

Comment: PHP 7.4 isn't fully supported by CiviCRM yet. The recommended version is PHP 7.3. https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements/#php-version

Comment: I changed PHP 7.4 to 7.3 and it did not fix the problem.